# Storage on arrays with multiple indexes in pseudocode?

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

I want to multiply some objects (it doesn't matter what they are, in this case, matrices) in the following way.
I am given an array, for example, as follows

```
array = [# # 0 0 # 0 0 0 # ... #] (#! = 0)
```

and for each index of this array i have associated an object in my case a Matrix

```
(M[1], M[2], ..., M[length (array)])
```

What I want to do, before carrying out the multiplication in succession `M[1]xM[2]x .... xM[length (array)]` is to perform a pre-multiplication between matrices whose indices are 0 and consecutive.

With this array

```
[# # 0 0 # 0 0 0 # ... #]
```

what I want to do is

```
M[1]xM[2]x(M[3]xM[4])xM[5]x(M[6]xM[7]xM[8])x ....
```

In particular, I want to save `M[1]` in an array at position 1, `M[2]` in an array at position 2, `M[3]xM[4]` in an array at position 3, `M[5]` in an array at position 4 ext.
To do this I need to scroll on at least 2 indexes. I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Unrelated: Index in C start from zero

Comment: To me this part is unclear: "In particular i want to save M[1] in an array at position 1...." Do you mean an array of matrices?

Comment: And why do you want to `multiply whose indices are 0`, won't the result be always 0?

Comment: Stefano, I see the question has the tag `maxima`. Do you mean you are working with the computer algebra system Maxima? (https://maxima.sourceforge.io)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matrices I'll illustrate this using simple strings. So instead of doing a multiplication, I'll use string concatenation to represent a matrix multiplication.

The code could be like:

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    #define LEN 9
    int input_arr[LEN] = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    char in_mat[LEN][LEN+1] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"};
    char out_mat[LEN][LEN+1] = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
    int j = 1;
    int prev_was_zero = input_arr[0] == 0;
    strcpy(out_mat[0], in_mat[0]);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < LEN; ++i)
    {
        if (input_arr[i] == 0)
        {
            if (prev_was_zero)
            {
                // Multiply with previous (here I do strcat instead of multiply)
                strcat(out_mat[j-1], in_mat[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(out_mat[j], in_mat[i]);
                ++j;
                prev_was_zero = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(out_mat[j], in_mat[i]);
            ++j;
            prev_was_zero = 0;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
    {
        puts(out_mat[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
cd
e
fgh
i
```

So the original 9 elements was reduce to 7 element where "cd" represents the multiplication of c and d. Likewise, "fgh" represents the multiplication of f, g and h.